# How to manage database context changes in production / CI

Tags: entity-framework, azure, ef-code-first, continuous-integration, azure-sql-database

I've spent the past few months developing a webApi solution that I'm ready to push up to Azure and hook into an Azure SQL Database. It was built with EF Code First.

I'm wondering what standard approaches there are to making changes to the database while in production.  I've been using database initializers up to this point but they all blow away data and re-seed.

I have a feeling this question is too broad for a concise answer, so I'd like to ask: **what terminology / processes / resources should a developer look into when designing a continuous integration workflow for a solution built with EF Code First and ASP.NET WebAPI, hosted as an Azure Service and hooked up to Azure SQL?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the subject of database migration, there was an interesting article on ASP.NET about this subject: [Strategies for Database Development and Deployment](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deploying-web-site-projects/strategies-for-database-development-and-deployment-cs).

Also since you are using EF Code First you will be able to use [Code First Migrations here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx) for database changes. This will allow you to better manage the changes you make to the database.

I'm not sure how far you want to go with continuous integration but since you are using Azure it might be worth it to have a look at [Continuous delivery to Windows Azure by using Team Foundation Service](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/publishing-with-tfs/). Although it relies on TFS in the cloud it's of course also possible to configure it with for example [Jenkins](http://woloski.com/2013/04/21/creating-jenkins-windows-azure/). However this does require a bit more work.

Answer (score 0):

I use this technic:

> 1- Create a clone database for your development environment if it doesn't exist.
>
> 2- Make the necessary changes in your dev environment and dev
>   database.
>
> 3- Deploy to your staging environment.
>
> 4- If you added some static datas
>   that should also exist in your prod database, use a tool like
>   [SQLDataExaminer](http://www.sqlaccessories.com/sql_data_examiner/) to find the data differences and execute the
>   insert, update, deletes for according rows. Use Schema Compare in VS2012 to find differences between your dev
>   and prod environment by selecting source as dev and target as prod.
>   And execute the script in your prod.
>
> 5- Swap the environments